# BtSync don't Have Permissions To Write To The Selected Folder

Tags: permissions, btsync

I'm getting an error when trying to add a folder to Btsync on Ubuntu 16.04. It says i don't have permission to write to the selected folder.

Every time i enable or disable btsync [using: `sudo systemctl enable btsync`] returns this error:

```
Synchronizing state of btsync.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable btsync
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `btsync' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `btsync' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

I'm a total newbie, but i can see this error is related to my problem. Does anyone know how to fix it?